# Eclipse Oxygen Java Code Completion Not Working?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I recently switched to Eclipse Oxygen (Build id: 20171005-1200) and my subjective opinion is that the Java code completion seems to be dumber than when I was using Eclipse Luna.  I was hoping that it was just something to do with my setup but I tried creating a brand new workspace and that did not help.  Below is a small test case where I received no proposals.  In this example, when I get to "Color." I expected Eclipse to show me a list of some of the color constants.  Instead Eclipse shows nothing.  Cycling through the various recommenders results in no proposals for everything.  Is anyone else experiencing this type of issue or have any idea how to resolve it?  I switched to Eclipse Oxygen because Lambda support in Eclipse Luna was buggy if the Lambda had generics but am otherwise disappointed by Oxygen compared to Luna

```
import java.awt.Color;

public enum Test {
    TEST1(Color.BLACK);

    private final Color color;

    private Test(final Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions/recommendations would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this only happen for `java.awt.*` types? If so, check whether you have those proposals filtered at `Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > type filters`. If so, try removing/disabling that filter.

Comment: @JohannesDorn I looked at what you suggested and I have nothing filtered out.  I changing Color to int and tried passing in Integer.MIN_VALUE but I got the same issue - no proposals after Integer

Answer (score 1):

this use to happen when you change the Eclipse version but keep using the old workspace...

create a new workspace for Oxygen and import the old projects into it..

Comment: I tried creating a new workspace and starting from a new project and it seems broken out of the box

Answer (score 1):

If you get the dreaded ‘Code Recommenders’ not working dialog box when using Java code completion:

Project -> Clean… -> Check Clean All -> click Clean

Worked for me with Oxygen 2 Java Developer:
  Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
  Build id: 20171218-0600
Probably due to older version of Eclipse baggage